# Applescript move Outlook email to sub folder

Tags: email, outlook, applescript, subdirectory

I'm using an Applescript to move email in Outlook to a folder by assigning a keyboard shortcut to the Applescript.  This is working great and I'm trying to create another script, but have the email in my inbox move to a subfolder that is not directly under my inbox.

Check out the script below.  The commented out line works, but the line where I'm trying to assign the subfolder is breaking.

How do I assign a subfolder in Applescript?  I'm trying "MyFolder/MySubfolder" via a "/", but that doesn't work.

```
on run {}
tell application "Microsoft Outlook"
    activate
    set msgSet to current messages
    if msgSet = {} then
        error "No messages selected. Select at least one message."
        error -128
    end if
    set theMsg to item 1 of msgSet
    set theAccount to account of theMsg
    --set archiveFolder to folder "MyFolder" of folder "Inbox" of theAccount
    set archiveFolder to folder "MyFolder/MySubfolder" of folder "Inbox" of theAccount
    repeat with aMessage in msgSet
        move aMessage to archiveFolder
    end repeat
end tell
```

end run

Answer (score 2):

Ok - I figured it out!

```
set topFolder to folder "Inbox" of theAccount
set subFolder to folder "MyFolder" of topFolder
set subFolder2 to folder "MySubfolder" of subFolder
```

Answer (score 1):

You chain them up long hand and in reverse;

e.g.,

```
set archiveFolder to folder "MySubfolder" of folder "MyFolder" of folder "Inbox" of theAccount
```